# No network available

Tags: networking, kernel, kubuntu, network-manager, internet

Running Kubuntu 18.04.

I had installed Cinnamon. Later removed it using `sudo apt-get remove`

Then, I did `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`.

Now, I'm able to log in to my KDE. But there's no network - wired, wireless, anything. That icon itself is missing.

How do I get my network back?

Comment: Maybe try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop`? And then reboot?

Comment: @DKBose It needs to download a tiny file but fails because it's unable to connect to the net :(

Comment: Oops! Then look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline assuming you can get access to another machine with internet, in particular, https://askubuntu.com/a/369863/248158

Comment: @DKBose Tried that. No luck. Even after reboot, there's still no network

Comment: Sorry to hear that!